# Android OS の詳細なシステムログを出力する方法を知りたい

Tags: android, monaca

現在monacaでAndroidアプリを開発しています。

エラーの詳細な内容を追跡するためAndroid OSのログを出力できないかと言われています。

root化すればシステムログ等にもアクセス出来るかもしれませんが、極力特殊な権限を使用したくないと思っています。

root化しなくてもシステムログを確認するような事は可能でしょうか？

Comment: Monacaについては詳しくないのですが、Android Studioのlogcatからは確認はできませんでしょうか? adbからコマンドラインでも利用できますのでテキストなどへ書き出しもできると思います。https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat?hl=ja

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32240120/android-system-log-file-location
を見てみると良いかもしれません